# testeInt.java:100: error: ']' expected

Tags: java

```
public static String byteToHexa(final byte bits){

   final int l = bits & 0xF;  
   final int h = bits >>> 4 & 0xF;  

   return String.valueOf(HEXAS[h]) + String.valueOf(HEXAS[l]);  
}  


public static String bytesToHexas(final byte[] bytes){

   final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();  
   final int length = bytes.length;  
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
       buffer.append(byteToHexa(byte[i]));  
   }  
   return buffer.toString();  
}
```

testeInt.java:100: error: ']' expected
            buffer.append(byteToHexa(byte[i]));

testeInt.java:100: error: ')' expected
            buffer.append(byteToHexa(byte[i]));

testeInt.java:100: error: ';' expected
            buffer.append(byteToHexa(byte[i]));

Comment: Please show your `byteToHexa(...)` method code.

Comment: Ah, this `byte[i]` should be `bytes[i]`. Note the difference.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35970547/edit).

Comment: Voting to close question as a *simple typographical error*.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing more than a typographical error:

`byte[i]` should be `bytes[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `byte` which is a reserved keyword in Java. The compiler expected an expression to be passed as an argument, and not a type-declaration keyword. You probably meant to reference `bytes` which is an argument to the `bytesToHexas` function.

Answer (score 0):

You just can not use  `byte[i]` your typo means maybe (100% sure) `bytes[i]` as in the method param `bytesToHexas(final byte[] bytes){`